# fatal error LNK1104 (.lib file not found) when linking MS C++ with Intel Fortran

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran

I have two files `source1.f90` and `main.cpp`. The Fortran file has a subroutine and the cpp file has a program that calls the Fortran subroutine

I compiled the Fortran file and the built a static library file using the following command line options

```
ifort source1.f90 /nologo /debug:full /Od /gen-interfaces /warn:interfaces /traceback /check:bounds /libs:static /threads /dbglibs /c

lib /out:lib1.lib source1.obj
```

But when I compiled the cpp file using

```
CL main.cpp /link LIB1.LIB
```

I get the following error

```
D:\temp>CL main.cpp /EHsc /link LIB1.LIB
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.60610.1 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 11.00.60610.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
LIB1.LIB
main.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ifmodintr.lib'
```

How do I fix this problem so that my program compiles?

Comment: Does this help? https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/394201

Comment: No I copied all the LIB files into the folder where I had my source code then the linking problem went away

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you miss the setting of the mixed programming environment in Visual studios. Just follow this link provided by intel:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/configuring-visual-studio-for-mixed-language-applications.

Or in short, add the fortran compiler include directory and library directory in the project configuration tab. In my case, the fortran compiler directory is "g:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries\windows\compiler\include\intel64", and the library directory is "g:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries\windows\compiler\lib\intel64_win".